# Are the tangent lines to a helix disjoint?

Tags: differential-geometry, curves

Let $H$ be the helix parametrized by $t \mapsto (\cos(t), \sin(t), t) : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}^3$. It seems like any two distinct tangent lines to $H$ will be disjoint – in fact I thought this was so clear that I wrote a problem on a worksheet asking students to find a curve whose distinct tangent lines are disjoint and just assumed this would be a solution. Now, as I'm writing the solutions, I'm having trouble actually showing that the tangent lines to $H$ are pairwise-disjoint.

Is there an easy way to see that any two distinct tangent lines to $H$ must be disjoint? Or, if this is false, is it easy to see why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Updated answer based on comments by @diracdeltafunk: the tangent lines are not all disjoint.**

By symmetry, it suffices to show that there are distinct tangent lines that intersect the line tangent to $(1,0,0)$.

The tangent line at $(1,0,0)$ can be parametrized as $\mathbf r_0(a) = (1,a,a)$. The tangent line at any other point $(\cos(t),\sin(t),t)$ can be parametrized as $\mathbf r_t(b) = (\cos(t) - b\sin(t),\sin(t)+b\cos(t),t+b)$. For these two lines to intersect, we require there to exist $a,b$ so that
$$
\begin{cases}
\cos(t) - b\sin(t) = 1 \\
\sin(t) + b\cos(t) = a \\
t + b = a.
\end{cases}\tag{$\ast$}
$$
The last equation reduces us to asking
$$
\begin{cases}
\cos(a-b) - b\sin(a-b) = 1 \\
\sin(a-b) + b\cos(a-b) = a, \\
\end{cases}
$$
or equivalently that
$$
\begin{pmatrix} \cos(a-b) & -\!\sin(a-b) \\ \sin(a-b) & \cos(a-b)\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}1 \\ b\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ a\end{pmatrix}.
$$

Since the matrix appearing in the last equation is a rotation matrix, it must be the case that $|b| = |a|$. Taking $a = b$ in ($\ast$) corresponds to the solution $\mathbf r_a = \mathbf r_0$. If we take $a = -b$ and let $a$ be a real number such that $a = \tan(a)$ (there are infinitely many such $a$), then we can show that $\mathbf r_0(a) = \mathbf r_{2a}(-a)$. One way to see this is to use the double-angle identities and the fact that for such an $a$, $a-\arctan(a)$ is an integer-multiple of $\pi$. This exhibits infinitely many distinct tangent lines (the $\mathbf r_{2a}$) that intersect any given tangent line ($\mathbf r_0$).

Comment: Thank you! A couple minutes ago I finally came up with a solution myself but it was much less clean than this – recognizing the rotation matrix is really nice.

Comment: @diracdeltafunk: It's a cool problem! I think another more "high falutin" solution could be to recognize the tangent lines as flow lines of a certain linear differential equation, and then to use the global existence and uniqueness of solutions to linear ODE to conclude that distinct tangent lines don't intersect.

Comment: Actually, I think there is an issue here. The fact that this is a rotation matrix only tells us that $\lvert a \rvert = \lvert b \rvert$, so we have to rule out the case where $a = -b$. However, this case cannot be ruled out! If $a$ is any real number such that $a = \tan(a)$ (there are infinitely many such $a$), then in fact $\mathbf{r}_0(a) = \mathbf{r}_{2a}(-a)$ (this uses the fact that for any such $a$, $a - \arctan(a)$ is an integer multiple of $\pi$).

Comment: @diracdeltafunk: I finally got around to incorporating your last comment into my post. It was a nice insight you had to take $a = \tan(a)$. I could not quite divine how you came upon that condition, but it works out, even though I had to grind through some algebra and trig identities to convince myself. Do you have a nice way of explaining how you found that condition and/or a nice way of verifying it? I also don't quite know what to make of my comment re: using ODE to show the lines are disjoint since we now know they're not, but I think it might be something fun to think through